# how to construct a php variable containing html code and php code in a php page that is called by ajax

Tags: php, html, jquery

```
$table="<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>FIRST NAME</th>
    <th>LAST NAME</th>
    <th>EMAIL</th>
    <th>GENDER</th>".
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result3))
    {
        $action="Action";
        $var=$action.$count;
         ."<th>" .$var. "</th>".
        $count=$count+1;

    } 

    ."        </tr>".

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
    {

         ."<tr>".
         "<td>".$row['firstname']."</td>".
         "<td>".$row['lastname']."</td>".
         "<td>".$row['email']."</td>".
        if($row['gender']=='m')
        {
            $gend='male';
        }
        else
        {
            $gend='female';
        }
         "<td>".$gend."</td>".

        $result3=$db->selectUserPermission($uid);
        $id=$row['userid'];
        $loginuser=$_SESSION['LOGINUSER'];
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result3))
        {

              ."<td>".
            if($row['permid']==1)
            {
                $permission="VIEW";
                $btnid=$id."_VIEW";
                 ."<button id=$btnid name=$btnid onclick='getFunctionView($id)'>".$permission."</button>".
            }
            else  if($row['permid']==2)
            {
                $permission="EDIT";
                $btnid=$id."_EDIT";
                 ."<button id=$btnid name=$btnid onclick='getFunctionEdit($id)';>".$permission."</button>".
            }
            else  if($row['permid']==3)
            {
                if($id!=1 || $id!=$loginuser)
                {
                $permission="DELETE";
                $btnid=$id."_DELETE";
                 ."<button id=$btnid name=$btnid onclick='getFunctionDelete($id)';>".$permission."</button>".
                }
            }
            else  if($row['permid']==4)
            {
                if($id!=1)
                {
                $permission="PERMISSION";
                $btnid=$id."_PERMISSION";
                 ."<button id=$btnid name=$btnid onclick='getFunctionPermission($id)';>".$permission."</button>".
                }
            }
            else  if($row['permid']==5 && $loginuser==$id)
            {
                $permission="ADD USER";
                 ."<button id=$btnid name=$btnid onclick='location.href=\"adduser.html\"'>".$permission."</button>".
            }
            else
            {
            }

             ."</td>".
        }
    }
     ."</tr>
     </table>";
     echo $table;
```

This is a code from a php page that is called by ajax.Here $result2 and $result3 are 2 result sets obtained using 2 sql queries.I want generate a table using theese two results and store that table into a php variable $table and in ajax ,i want to assign it directly as a html text,ajax code is shown below.

```
   $(document).ready(function(){

    var temp='getUser';
    $.ajax ({
                type:'GET',
                url: 'listdetails.php',
                data:{ud:temp},
                success:function(data)
                        {
                            document.getElementByID("userList").innerHTML=data;
                        }

           });
```

});

And my problem is in creating php variable $table.It is showing error in every concatination( "." ).this is the error message "Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_WHILE in C:\wamp\www\listdetails.php on line 39".Can any one suggest a good method for making php variable $table.and remember that this $table is in php page called by ajax.

Answer (score 3):

You're using the concatenations wrong.

- Don't concatenate a variable assignment ($someVar = ) with a conditional (if) or loop (while) statement
- Don't put a . after a ; or } because these characters terminate the previous command and you can't start the next command with .

Here's a reworked version of the first part of your code to get you started:

```
$table="<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>FIRST NAME</th>
<th>LAST NAME</th>
<th>EMAIL</th>
<th>GENDER</th>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result3))
{
    $action="Action";
    $table.="<th>" .$action.$count. "</th>";
    $count++;
} 

$table .= "        </tr>";
```

Comment: you are still using a . in the loop

Answer (score 0):

```
$sTable = '
<table>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
 </tr>';

while( false ) {
 $sTable .= '';
}

$sTable .= '
 </table>';

echo $sTable;
```

Or as I would do

```
$sBuffer = '';
while( code goes here ) {
 $sBuffer .= '
 <tr>
  <td></td>
 </tr>';
}


echo '
<table>
 <tr>
  <td></td>
 </tr>
 ' . $sBuffer . '
</table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering all you want to do is echo the table, I would end/start PHP only when I need it. The cleaned code is below.

```
<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>FIRST NAME</th>
<th>LAST NAME</th>
<th>EMAIL</th>
<th>GENDER</th>
<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result3))
{
        $action="Action";
        $var=$action.$count;  //$count is not defined yet in your example, first time will be ''
        echo "<th>" .$var. "</th>";
        $count=$count+1;
}
?>
</tr>

<?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
{
    ?>
    <tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['firstname']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['lastname']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['email']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo (($row['gender']=='m') ? 'male' : 'female'); ?></td>

    <?php
    $result3=$db->selectUserPermission($uid);
    $id=$row['userid'];
    $loginuser=$_SESSION['LOGINUSER'];
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result3))
    {
        echo "<td>";

        switch ($row['permid']) {
            case 1:
                $permission="VIEW";
                $btnid=$id."_VIEW";
                echo "<button id=$btnid name=$btnid onclick='getFunctionView($id)'>".$permission."</button>";
                break;
            case 2:
                $permission="EDIT";
                $btnid=$id."_EDIT";
                echo "<button id=$btnid name=$btnid onclick='getFunctionEdit($id)';>".$permission."</button>";
                break;
            case 3:
                if($id!=1 || $id!=$loginuser)
                {
                    $permission="DELETE";
                    $btnid=$id."_DELETE";
                     echo "<button id=$btnid name=$btnid onclick='getFunctionDelete($id)';>".$permission."</button>";
                }
                break;
            case 4:
                if($id!=1)
                {
                    $permission="PERMISSION";
                    $btnid=$id."_PERMISSION";
                    echo "<button id=$btnid name=$btnid onclick='getFunctionPermission($id)';>".$permission."</button>";
                }
                break;
            case 5:
                if($loginuser==$id)
                {
                    $permission="ADD USER";
                    echo "<button id=$btnid name=$btnid onclick='location.href=\"adduser.html\"'>".$permission."</button>";
                }
                break;
        }

        echo "</td>";
    }
}
?>
</tr>
</table>
```